# Adafruit Flora breakout board and SI1445

Tags: arduino, arduino-ide

I'm trying to set up my new flora breakout board (here's the link for clarification: https://www.adafruit.com/product/659) using the test code given with the library; however, when I go to upload the code I get an error message saying that the board cannot be found. After looking up some stuff online I tried looking in the board manager on the Arduino ide and I cannot find anything for the adafruit flora board that I need. If anyone knows how to install the adafruit flora board or knows of a site to explain that I would appreciate the help. This is the link I found for installing the board: https://learn.adafruit.com/add-boards-arduino-v164/installing-boards

```
/*************************************************** 
  This is a library for the Si1145 UV/IR/Visible Light Sensor

  Designed specifically to work with the Si1145 sensor in the
  adafruit shop
  ----> https://www.adafruit.com/products/1777

  These sensors use I2C to communicate, 2 pins are required to  
  interface
  Adafruit invests time and resources providing this open source code, 
  please support Adafruit and open-source hardware by purchasing 
  products from Adafruit!

  Written by Limor Fried/Ladyada for Adafruit Industries.  
  BSD license, all text above must be included in any redistribution
 ****************************************************/

#include <Wire.h>
#include "Adafruit_SI1145.h"

Adafruit_SI1145 uv = Adafruit_SI1145();

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  
  Serial.println("Adafruit SI1145 test");
  
  if (! uv.begin()) {
    Serial.println("Didn't find Si1145");
    while (1);
  }

  Serial.println("OK!");
}

void loop() {
  Serial.println("===================");
  Serial.print("Vis: "); Serial.println(uv.readVisible());
  Serial.print("IR: "); Serial.println(uv.readIR());
  
  // Uncomment if you have an IR LED attached to LED pin!
  //Serial.print("Prox: "); Serial.println(uv.readProx());

  float UVindex = uv.readUV();
  // the index is multiplied by 100 so to get the
  // integer index, divide by 100!
  UVindex /= 100.0;  
  Serial.print("UV: ");  Serial.println(UVindex);

  delay(1000);
}
```

error message:

```
avrdude: ser_open(): can't open device
```

Comment: This is not an Adafruit tech support site.

Comment: Thank you! @TomServo I actually did check the adafruit tech support sites and couldn't find anything besides the link I included in my question. Trust me I wouldn't go to this website as a first try to find an answer.

Comment: This would definitely be an appropriate question if you actually include the test code and the error message.  Also, If you answer your own question please post the answer separately and accept it ( you can self accept your own answer )

Comment: @chrisMaggiulli Thank you for the advice! I didn't realize i could answer my own question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

found the solution using this website https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-arduino-ide-setup/arduino-1-dot-6-x-ide

Needed to go to preferences and add the GitHub URL for the adafruit flora and other boards

Comment: Now click the check mark to accept it. This is definitely an appropriate question and response